# jquery ui dialog opens only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a button that opens a dialog when clicked.
The dialog displays a div that was hidden

After I close the dialog by clicking the X icon, the dialog can't be opened again.

Comment: post code or link... :-(

Comment: What code are you using to hide and show the dialog?

Comment: some code would be awesome. generally, don't forget to make sure that you're not causing any errors when/while closing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Scott Gonzalez (of the jQuery UI Team) talks about the reason alot of people have this problem when getting started with jQuery UI in a recent blog post: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

An excerpt:

> The problem that users often encounter
>   with dialogs is that they try to
>   instantiate a new dialog every time
>   the user performs some action
>   (generally clicking a link or a
>   button).  This is an understandable
>   mistake because at first glance it
>   seems like calling .dialog()  on an
>   element is what causes the dialog to
>   open.  In reality what is happening is
>   that a new dialog instance is being
>   created and then that instance is
>   being opened immediately after
>   instantiation.  The reason that the
>   dialog opens is because dialogs have
>   an autoOpen option, which defaults to
>   true.  So when a user calls .dialog() 
>   on an element twice, the second call
>   is ignored because the dialog has
>   already been instantiated on that
>   element.
>
> Solution:
>
> The simple solution to this problem is
>   to instantiate the dialog with
>   autoOpen set to false and then call
>   .dialog('open') in the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('This dialog will show every time!')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog'
        });

    $('#opener').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if the dialog is initialized and showed in the event? Is there a performance risk or is it just bad practice?

Comment: doesn't work, maybe is just a bad design of this dialog?

Answer (score 9):

Are you using the ui dialog? You should post some code so we can see what is causing your problem. But here iss a guess (because I made this same mistake recently). When using ui dialog you have to initialize the dialog only once.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen:false,
     modal:'true',
     width:450,
     height:550
  });
 $('#MyButton').click(openDialog);    

});
```

This code, initializes the dialog but does not show it. The openDialog function will then open the dialog box when MyButton is clicked.

```
   var openDialog = function(){

       $('#dialog').load('loadurl.php');//load with AJAX

      //optionally change options each time it is clicked
       $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'buttons',{
          "Cancel":function(){
             $('#dialog').dialog('close');
          }
      });

     //actually open the dialog
     $('#dialog').dialog('open');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the accepted answer i would like to add that you need to pay attention when using this in an asp.net updatepanel.
If you click the button then a postback will happen, the popup will open but won't open a second time because of the postback that happened. So you should make sure that the button you use to open the popup does not postback.
ie:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return false;">Click me</asp:LinkButton>
```