# Jquery modal dialog shows only at first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-dialog

The following code works fine for only the first click event. However for any subsequent click nothing happens.

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add it" onClick="javascript:Add(); return false;">

function Add()
{
   $(function(){
    var dialogOpts = {
        width: 880,
        height: 270,
        minWidth: 880,
        minHeight: 270,
        maxWidth: 890,
        maxHeight: 300
    };
    $("#add").dialog(dialogOpts);
    });
 }
```

If I remove return false from:

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add it" onClick="javascript:Add(); return false;">
```

I get it working for Firefox but in IE8 the window shows for one or two seconds and then it disappears (cache cleaned and all).

I've seem many examples in this web about this problem, but I am afraid I'm too new to jquery to apply them :(

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're using an `onclick` attribute, you don't need to put `javascript: `, since it's already interpreted as Javascript.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes is gives an assumption that some javascript is being invoked.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701942/jquery-ui-dialog-opens-only-once - see this blog post: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Comment: @Shiv onclick content already IS interpreted as javascript, so there is no need for the `javascript`

Comment: @Christoph Yeah thats what I meant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this to instantiate your dialog:

```
$(function(){

    $diag = $("#add");
    var dialogOpts = {
        width: 880,
        height: 270,
        minWidth: 880,
        minHeight: 270,
        maxWidth: 890,
        maxHeight: 300,
        autoOpen: false
    };
    $diag.dialog(dialogOpts); // This instantiates the dialog once.
    //And then add this eventhandler:
    $("input[name='add']").click(function(){
       $diag.dialog('open');
    });
});
```

and remove all that inline `onclick` stuff - avoid it wherever you can...

Comment: $diag.dialog is not a function pointing to $diag.dialog(dialogOpts);

Comment: @user523129 what are you trying to say? I don't understand... The `$diag` var remains in this scope the same, why shouldn't it work?

Comment: that I get this error in Firebug's console:  
$diag.dialog is not a function and no modal opens.

Comment: @user523129 well, i fixed my typo;) Try again.

Comment: $("input[name='add']").on is not a function

Comment: you have an old version of jquery then. I will tweak my code.

Comment: now no errors but no modal shows :( I really apreciate your effort, thanks!

Comment: jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js is my version

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove some of your code :) "javascript:" is not necessary

```
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add it" onClick="Add();">
```

and on dom ready part is not needed

```
function Add()
{
    var dialogOpts = {
        width: 880,
        height: 270,
        minWidth: 880,
        minHeight: 270,
        maxWidth: 890,
        maxHeight: 300
    };
    $("#add").dialog(dialogOpts);
 }
```

Comment: thanks but still the same as when I remove return false. Works for Firefox but when in IE8 the modal disappears after a second or two :(