# Grabing a data attribute of a clicked element?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a link that opens a modal when clicked, however that element also has a data-id="#id here" attribute that I need to grab so I can pass it to my php script for processing. How can I accomplish this?

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#edit_general').click(editModal);

});

function editModal(event)
{
var modal = $('#editModal');
modal.modal({
    show: true
});
}
```

My html:

```
<li><a id="edit_general" href="#editModal" data-uid="<?php echo $u->id; ?>">Edit General</a></li>
```

I tried using the this keyword but it didn't work.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can get using $(this).data('id');

Comment: Thank you, it works now, however the modal only pops up for the first entry. The html is echo'd out in a foreach loop. However the modal only pops up for the first user, any idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/szS2J/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/ug7ze/

```
$(this).data('uid')
```

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

like this:

```
$('#edit_general').click(editModal);
      $(this).data('uid')
```

**full**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit_general').click(editModal);

});

function editModal(event) {
    alert($(this).data('uid'));
    var modal = $('#editModal');
    modal.modal({
        show: true
    });
}​
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, however the modal only pops up for the first entry. The html is echo'd out in a foreach loop. However the modal only pops up for the first user, any idea why that is happening?

Comment: No Worries @user1701398 Glad it helped `:)`, hmm, hope for modal you are closing modal properly and then recreating for the second input? Seems like the binding issue between modal and input box,  can you flick a fiddle man, I will take a look. `:)`

Comment: All the code I have is posted above, how would I go about unbinding it when the modal is closed? I am using bootstrap modal plugin if that helps.

Comment: By the way, even if it's a fresh page load, it still doesn't work for any other entries, only for the first one. I tried using live() instead of click() but still no luck

Comment: @user1701398 read this might help[: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701942/jquery-ui-dialog-opens-only-once oh by the ay `:)` .live is deprecated if you keen for why live is deprecated read this **Please Note: `.on` is available 1.7.2 JQ and above :)** ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115864/whats-wrong-with-the-jquery-live-method/11115926#11115926

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is slightly different, the dialog still opens again even if I close it. The problem is that it only opens for the first entry in my table. It's basically a table with all the user data and there is the edit general button for each user. For the first entry/user if I click it the dialog opens fine, but no other ones even open the dialog.

Comment: Ah, LOL @user1701398 `:)` it is bind to only on `id` - `#edit_general` **-** Thats why it only gets open forone input box - perhaps add a class attribute and rest keep the same!

Comment: Yea but every "Edit General" link has the id of "edit_general" if I add a class they will all have a class of "whatever_class" and then it would be the same problem? Is there a better way to do this? Im sorry that im asking so much, im just slightly new to javascript and can't figure this one out

Comment: No worries bruv - all good `:)` - So; In a HTML DOM **-** `id` - identifies **UNIQUE**-ness :) of the element, you cannot have mulitple same id's where as you **CAN HAVE** multiple same `class` attribute and if you bind one event with that calss it will get bind to everything element with that class `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value using the attr method: `$(this).attr('data-uid')`

Answer (score 1):

Like this stored in data_id.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#edit_general').click(function() {
         var data_id = $(this).data('uid');
         var modal = $('#editModal');
            modal.modal({
            show: true
         });
      });
   });
```