# Jquery Modal Doesnt Work On Second Click on content delivered via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am loading some html into a div from an ajax call. With in this html content, when clicked opens a jquery modal. 
On the first click the modal opens as it should, but on subsequent clicks the modal will not open and get this error in the console:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
```

Here is the html that is generated via the ajax call which when clicked will open the modal:

```
 <div class="edit" rel="630000311">630000311</div>
```

Here is the CSS as it relates to the edit class:

```
.edit {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: blue;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding-left:5px;
   text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .ui-widget-overlay {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
   }
```

here is my jquery

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('body').on('click','.edit', function(){ 
      var myDialogX = $(this).position().left - $(this).outerWidth();
      var myDialogY = $(this).position().top - ( $(document).scrollTop() +      $('.ui-dialog').outerHeight() );
   $("#viewDialog").dialog({
       width: 1140,
       modal: true,
       position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
   });
   var partID = $(this).attr('rel');
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: "parthistory.php",
            data: {
                "partID" : partID
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#viewDialog").html(data);

            }
        });
});
});
```

I have tried adding $(document).trigger('ready'); into the success, but this does not help

**Note** Here is the jquery I am loading:

```
code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
```

Comment: First thing you should do is add handlers for "complete" and "error". This will let you know if there are js errors associated with it and what that problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#viewDialog").dialog({
           width: 1140,
           modal: true,
           autoOpen: false,
           position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' }
       });
       $('body').on('click','.edit', function(){ 
           $("#viewDialog").dialog('open');
           var myDialogX = $(this).position().left - $(this).outerWidth();
           var myDialogY = $(this).position().top - ( $(document).scrollTop() + $('.ui-dialog').outerHeight() );
           var partID = $(this).attr('rel');
           $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: 'GET',
                url: "parthistory.php",
                data: { "partID" : partID },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#viewDialog").html(data);
                }
           });
       });
   });
```

It is a common mistake to instantiate the dialog inside of an event such as a click, and then as a result, the dialog will work the first time due to an autoOpen property being true by default. On the next click, the attempt to instantiate the dialog will be ignored, and the dialog will not open.

**The fix:** Instantiate your dialog outside of the on click, set autoOpen to false, and open it inside of the desired event instead.

[This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701942/jquery-ui-dialog-opens-only-once) has a great answer that explains this more in-depth.

Also, you can remove the comma after you set your position value in your dialog since it is the last property that you are setting.

**Sidenote:**
Check your versions of jQuery that you are importing. Odd problems similar to this can arise when multiple versions or out-dated versions of jQuery are imported.

Comment: It works the first time so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Fixed, added a side note instead to address common importing issues. Thank you.